# Why does my code only work with small amount of data?(run-time error 1004-VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a code that lists me every word that occurs in a given column and the number of times each word occurs(the cells contain text). If I try to run it for my C column that contains larger texts, I get a 'run_time error 1004' in line: 'Cells(MyRow, 7).Value = K'. How could I modify this code to make it work on large amount of data?

```
Sub WordCount()
Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, oMax As Double, K As Variant, Msg As String, vWords As Variant, myWord As Variant
Set Rng = Range(Range("B2"), Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each Dn In Rng
        vWords = Split(Dn.Text, " ")
            For Each myWord In vWords
                If Not .Exists(myWord) Then
                .Add myWord, 1
            Else
                .Item(myWord) = .Item(myWord) + 1
            End If
            Next
        Next
oMax = Application.Max(Application.Transpose(.Items))
MyRow = 2
For Each K In .keys
    If .Item(K) = oMax Then
        Msg = Msg & K & ","
    End If
    Cells(MyRow, 8).Value = .Item(K)
    Cells(MyRow, 7).Value = K
    MyRow = MyRow + 1
Next K
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What's a sample value of `K` when this fails?

Comment: BTW, this will run much quicker if you limit the number of time the code accesses the worksheet directly.  Use Variant arrays which can bulk load in and out.

Comment: What is `MyRow` when it fails? Declare `Dim MyRow As Long` properly. Use `Option Explicit`

Comment: I can not find a solution to identify what K is when the code fails. I declared MyRow as you asked.

Comment: hold your mouse over `K` after the error popped up and you clicked debug. The tool tip will show the value. Or use `Debug.Print K` or use the "local" window in the VBA editor.

Comment: Ok thank you! K equals '==='

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the issue is you cannot put three `===` signs in a cell because Excel tries to treat everything that starts with a `=` as formula and `===` is no valid formula so it fails.

Replace

```
Cells(MyRow, 7).Value = K
```

with

```
Cells(MyRow, 7).Value = IIf(Left$(K, 1) = "=", "'" & K, K)
```

this puts a `'` infront of everything starting with a `=` sign. So it is treated as text not formula. Don't worry the apostrophe is not shown in the cell.